# nape - targeting only one body

Tags: game-physics, starling-framework, nape

I have a few body in nape one is a loop of 'baddies' the other is a single 'hero' I call my updateGraphics function but how to I taget the hero within this function, I have tried **hero.userData.graphic.x** but it passes in an array of bodies, is there any way to taget my hero  body by id or name?

hero = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);

badguy = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC, new Vec2(Math.random()*1280, -100)) // loops to generate lots;

```
private function updateGraphics(b:Body):void {


        b.userData.graphic.x = b.position.x;
        b.userData.graphic.y = b.position.y;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to target 'hero' inside of that function? Why not just call it 'on' hero:

updateGraphics(hero);